# Chrome Storage with Angular-Material - Not Writing, Value Reads as Undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, angular-material

I made a small test project to learn how to use google storage, and it is not working. It is not throwing any errors, it just isn't writing. If I read out the key value, it just returns undefined.
I'll put my code below...

manifest.json -

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "DataTest",
    "version": "1.0",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "favicon.ico",
        "default_popup": "index.html",
        "default_title": "Data Test"
      },
    "permissions": [
        "storage"
      ]
}
```

index.html just has my app.component in it - here is my app.component.html

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Input</mat-label>
  <input matInput [(ngModel)]='myText'>
</mat-form-field>
<br>
<button mat-stroked-button (click)="saveChanges()" color='accent'>Save Text</button>
<button mat-stroked-button (click)="printText()" color='primary'>print stored value</button>
```

and this is my app.component.ts file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'dataStoreTest';
  myText = '';

  printText(){
    var currentText = chrome.storage.local.get(['storedText'], function(){});  // <-------- btw, for some reason if I don't have a callback function it breaks... is it required or am I using chrome.storage wrong?
    console.log(currentText);
  }

  saveChanges() {
    var txt = this.myText;
    chrome.storage.local.set({'storedText': txt});
  }

}
```

Comment: See the documentation: this method doesn't return anything, it uses a callback.

Comment: Dang... Yeah, I completely misunderstood. It's working now - Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As wOxxOm pointed out to me, the chrome.storage.get has no return value, it just accesses the storage. That's why a callback function is required. 
It was fixed by changing my app.compoent.ts printText() function to-

```
printText(){
    chrome.storage.local.get(['storedText'], function(value){
      console.log(value);
    });
```